# Makefile pattern rules

Tags: makefile

Is it possible to write pattern rule like:

```
%.o: %.c %.h
    <some action>
```

so it accepts not one but any number of headers, because I have:

```
main.o: main.c $(HEADERS)
```

so it doesen't fit to standard implicit rule, because of many .h files that main.c depends on, so is it possible to make an implicit rule, that would accept such input, or should I just write

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINE_OPT) $(INCLUDE) -c  $<
```

explicitly?

Comment: What version of Make are you using?

Comment: I am using GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
```

However, in general, you probably don't want all source files to be dependent on all header files.  You should look into auto-generating the prerequisite lists; the Make manual talks about this a bit: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

In GNUMake you can write

```
main.o: $(HEADERS)
```

and the built-in implicit rule will work. If you want to handle dependencies automatically, [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html) is superior to the one in the GNUMake manual.